# Calling Methods with Arguments

Tags: java, arrays, methods

> Write the following methods:
>   13. A method named loadScores that will be passed the size of an   array, prompt the user to enter the appropriate number of floating point  grades, then return the loaded array.

I wrote the method, but the problem comes when I try to call it. Here's what I have:

```
public class ArrayHandout {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     int size = loadScores(size);
     double[] scoresArray = loadScores(size);
  } // end main

  public static double[] loadScores(int size) {
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.println("How many scores would you like to enter?");
    size = input.nextInt();
    double[] scoresArray = new double[size]; 

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < scoresArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a score:");
        scoresArray[i] = input.nextDouble(); 
    }// end for

    System.out.println(scoresArray[i]); 
    return scoresArray;   
  } // end loadScores  
} // end class
```

I have changed a few things in an attempt to correct some errors I was having when I wrote the original code, and unfortunately don't even remember what those changes were or if they fixed the problems since I can't get it to compile now. I do know that the problem I was having when I could get the original to compile was that it was only printing the first number in the array rather than printing the entire array. Like I said, I don't know if that problem has been corrected since now when I try to compile I receive the following error message:

> 1 error found:
>       File: C:\Users\HiTechRedneck\Desktop\Fall     2013\PlayingwithJava\ArrayHandout.java  [line: 6]
>       Error: incompatible types
>         required: int
>         found:    double[]

I know that `size` needs to be declared in `main` because previously I was getting the "cannot find variable size" error, but I think the fact that I'm trying to declare `int size` as `loadScores(size)` is throwing it off since the variable I'm declaring is also an argument in the method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `int size = loadScores(size);`

That is not what you want. Shouldn't `size` just be a number, like 5?

Comment: But the size depends on what the user inputs in the method, that's why I'm getting stuck.

Comment: If you're reading `size` inside the function, then there's no need to take it as a parameter to the function-- that would mean that you know the value of `size` before it's read!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend blindly changing your original code without making sure the changes are helping correct your issues. Especially if you're not commenting the changes, or better yet commenting *out* the supposed offending code. Back up the original, make small changes, ensure they work then merge with the original.

Comment: Ideally you should just have a github or related repository where you push your code each time you make a substantial change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line `int size = loadScores(size)` is incorrect. `loadScores` has a return type of `double[]`, so you need to assign that return value as such.

Just delete that one line and everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`int size = loadScores(size);` is throwing an error because loadScores returns an array of type double.

Since the task just wants a code snippet you could probably give size an arbitrary value and pass that in. Or you could get rid of size in main and just pass a number in:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] scoresArray = loadScores(5);
}
```

Edit: Also worth noting that the print statement after the for loop will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException since i is now greater than the length of the array. If you want to print the contents of the scoresArray you'll need another loop to traverse through each element.

Second edit: If you're prompting the user for a size you should run your prompt for that in the main method and then pass that to loadScores().

Answer (score 0):

You don't need size at all before you call the function as you read it in the function
your declaration could be :

```
public static double[] loadScores()
```

and call

```
loadScores()
```

in main. Example:

```
 public class ArrayHandout {   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     double[] scoresArray = loadScores();  
     //do whatever you want here or change declaration of 
     //the function to void and do not return anything
   }  

   public static double[] loadScores() {
     Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in); 

     System.out.println("How many scores would you like to enter?");
     int size = input.nextInt();
     double[] scoresArray = new double[size]; 

     int i;
     for(i = 0; i < scoresArray.length; i++) {
       System.out.println("Please enter a score:");
       scoresArray[i] = input.nextDouble(); 
     }// end for

     System.out.println(scoresArray[i]); 
     return scoresArray;      
  }
}
```

if you don't use the returned array it would be better to do it like this:

```
public class ArrayHandout {   
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    loadScores(); 
  }  

  public static void loadScores() {
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.println("How many scores would you like to enter?");
    int size = input.nextInt();
    double[] scoresArray = new double[size]; 

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < scoresArray.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("Please enter a score:");
      scoresArray[i] = input.nextDouble(); 
    }// end for

    System.out.println(scoresArray[i]);   
  }
}
```

(When a method doesn't return anything  you have to specify it by using the void keyword in its signature)-You also need validation but I was only answering to  the specific problem -without validation your program will still fail if incompatible values are given.